# In SwiftUI #Preview is crashing when using @Environment property wrapper (Observable Macro)

Tags: swiftui, observable, preview

I am using the `Observable` macro and when I use `@Environment` property wrapper to instance my model the preview stop working. Sample code below

```
import SwiftUI
import Observation

@Observable class Library {
    // ...
}
```

Now in my main app I created an instance of Library and add that instance to the environment

```
@main
struct BookReaderApp: App {
    @State private var library = Library()


    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LibraryView()
                .environment(library)
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I want to retrieve the Library instance from any view using the `@Environment` property wrapper the preview stop working completely (Assume the `BoolView` actually exist)

```
struct LibraryView: View {
    @Environment(Library.self) private var library
    
    var body: some View {
        List(library.books) { book in
            BookView(book: book)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    LibraryView()
}
```

If I go back and don't use the `Observable` macro and just use the `ObservableObject` with `@StateObject`, `.environemntObject` and `@EnvironmentObject` the **#Preview** work fine.

This `Observable` macro is "related" new.
Any idea why this is happening? Is there any workaround? I am working with Xcode Version 15.2. Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: What does the crash say? Also this example does not show you injecting the object in the preview

Comment: The crash didn't say nothing helpful and to be honest I thought it was not necessary to inject the object in the preview. In any case the @MatBumpy answer did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an observable class using `@Environment(Type.self)...`, you are implicitly telling the view that the environment object will be present. However, in your preview you're not providing one, and the crash happens when the view tries to access the non-existent object.

There's no need to create a separate EnvironmentKey, as this goes against the ethos of the Observable environment feature. All you need to do is provide an environment copy in your preview.

The following would be sufficient:

```swift
#Preview {
    LibraryView()
        .environment(Library())
}
```

However, it might be worth creating a dummy example object with values that would demonstrate your view's capabilities, e.g.:

```swift
extension Library {
  static var example: Library = Library(books: [/* ... */])
}

#Preview {
  LibraryView()
    .environment(Library.example)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For previewing you can use the preview version of your library, e.g.

```
#Preview {
    LibraryView()
        .environment(Library.preview)
}
```

There is however a mistake in your `App` code. When `@State` is an `@Observable` class it needs to be optional and init afterwards like in `onAppear`. This is because `@State` inits its default value every time the View is init with is fine if its a value but a major memory leak if its an object being init on the heap.

```
@main
struct BookReaderApp: App {
    @State private var library: Library?

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if let library {
                LibraryView()
                    .environment(library)
            }
            else {
                Text("Library not init")
                    .onAppear {
                        library = Library()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more info about this in the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

> **Store observable objects**
> You can also store observable objects that
> you create with the Observable() macro in State; for example:
>
> ```
> @Observable class Library {
>     var name = "My library of books"
>     // ... }
>
>
> struct ContentView: View {
>     @State private var library = Library()
>
>
>     var body: some View {
>         LibraryView(library: library)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> A State property always instantiates its default value when SwiftUI instantiates the view. For this reason, avoid side effects and
> performance-intensive work when initializing the default value. For
> example, if a view updates frequently, allocating a new default object
> each time the view initializes can become expensive. Instead, you can
> defer the creation of the object using the task(priority:_:) modifier,
> which is called only once when the view first appears: struct
>
> ```
> ContentView: View {
>     @State private var library: Library?
>
>
>     var body: some View {
>         LibraryView(library: library)
>             .task {
>                 library = Library()
>             }
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> Delaying the creation of the observable state object ensures that unnecessary allocations of the object doesn’t happen each time
> SwiftUI initializes the view. Using the task(priority:_:) modifier is
> also an effective way to defer any other kind of work required to
> create the initial state of the view, such as network calls or file
> access.

Comment: In this instance, `App` is only instantiated once, so declaring a State variable with a default value within it is fine. But it's a good reminder for state in other views that might be created and destroyed during an app's lifetime.

Comment: I just wonder how much we can rely on App always only being init once!

Comment: The @main App is the entry point for the app – it will only be instantiated when the application is started. Note that https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/app shows an example of an environment object instantiated as state owned by the app (albeit with an `ObservableObject` class rather than an `@Observable`).

Comment: But if you remember when SwiftUI launched `ContentView` used to only be init once and that is the reason so many property wrappers are broken, e.g. `@FetchRequest` because they were never designed to be in a `View` that was re-init. Chances are that could happen with `App`.